pip install entire Python script as a command line executable via pyproject.toml
I am helping to write a pyproject.toml file for a Python package, and the author has written two Python scripts (not functions, but the script itself) that they would like to use as command-line executables. The folder structure looks as follows:
___ bin
|   |__ script1.py
|   |__ script2.py
|__ src 
    |__ module1.py
    |__ module2.py

Reading the setuptools docs, I can see that functions within scripts can be pointed to using the string "bin.script1:func1". However, in this case, the script itself is supposed to be the executable. All of the functions for the package are in the src folder, but the executables are in bin.
In such a situation, how should I configure the [pyproject.scripts] section of the pyproject.toml file such that it can be installed properly with pip? The relevant (I think) sections of my pyproject.toml configuration are as such at the moment:
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = [
  "setuptools",
]
...
...
[project.scripts]
Script1 = "bin:Script1.py"
Script2 = "bin:Script2.py"
...
...
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = [
    "src",
    "bin",
]

Feedback would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74955996/7976758 You can try [tool.setuptools]script-files. If that doesn't work your only solution is to return to setup.cfg/setup.py like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74355524/7976758 . Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyproject.toml%5D+scripts
